# XmlTextReader and embedded resource DTD

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, dtd, xmltextreader

I'm trying to create a single EXE with no dependencies (spare the .NET Framework :-). The program involves parsing a bunch of XML docs (using XmlTextReader) that share the same DTD. The DTD is referred to by its name alone in the doc, so till now I've had it as "Copy if Newer" so it's in the same folder as the EXE itself.

Now I'd like to embed this DTD as an embedded resource in my project. I assume I'll need a custom XmlResolver to make my XmlTextReader happy, but I wasn't sure what that looked like.  What's the secret sauce?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use `XmlTextReader`. You should use `XmlReader.Create()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no secret sauce. Just Google for "XmlResolver", and you'll find the "[System.Xml.XmlResolver class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx)" article. At the bottom, you'll find a link to "[Customizing the XmlUrlResolver class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669135.aspx)".

Use an instance of your custom resolver as the XmlResolver property of the XmlReaderSettings instance that you use in your XmlReader.Create call.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. But you must admit the sauce was closer to worcestershire than ketchup. :-)

Comment: Helpful, but an example would have been better since there are none on MSDN.

Comment: @night I assume a certain level of competence in the audience.